# Powershell HashTable default sorting does not correspond with Hashtable constructor

Tags: powershell, hashtable

I've created this PS hastable for computer hardware:

```
$PCHardware = @{
    CPU = (Get-CIMInstance Win32_Processor).Name
    RAM = "$((Get-CimInstance Win32_ComputerSystem).TotalPhysicalMemory /1gb | % { '{0:0.##}' -f $_})"+"GB"
    Disk = (Get-CimInstance Win32_DiskDrive).model
    GPU = (Get-CimInstance Win32_VideoController).name
    Motherboard = (Get-CIMInstance Win32_BaseBoard).product
}
```

The problem I'm facing is that instead of this:

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| CPU | Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700K CPU @ 4.20GHz |
| RAM | 15.96GB |
| Disk | SAMSUNG MZVLV256HCHP-00000 |
| GPU | NVIDIA Quadro M2000 |
| Motherboard | Z270M Extreme4 |

I get this:

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| GPU | NVIDIA Quadro M2000 |
| CPU | Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700K CPU @ 4.20GHz |
| RAM | 15.96GB |
| Disk | SAMSUNG MZVLV256HCHP-00000 |
| Motherboard | Z270M Extreme4 |

What sorting rules does the Hashtable follow?
Is not alphabetical by "Name" nor alphabetical by "Value".

Is there a way for it to follow my constructor format?

Thanks.

Comment: Probably want a [ordered]@{} hash table

Comment: hashtable keys don't follow a specific order, if you want an ordered hashtable use `[ordered]@{ }` to initialize a `System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary`.

Comment: Thank you both, I did not know of that type. Appreciated.